# How do I modify menu links depending on context?

Tags: navigation

I'm trying to create a menu for a department & group-based company such as:

- Presentation (`/<department>/<group>/presentation`)
- Projects (`/<department>/<group>/projects`)
- Personnel (`/<department>/<group>/personnel`)

Instead of having one static menu per `<department>/<group>`, what should be a proper approach to create just one dynamic menu which automagically updates its links to `<department>/<group>`?

Comment: How did you implement those "groups", using any specific module for that? Also, is it possible that a single user belongs to mutliple "groups"?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens
No, `/<department>/<group>/[presentation | projects | personnel]` is just an "URL alias" as defined in `URL Path Settings` when creating a content node. No particular users are involved in viewing contents.

Comment: merci for clarifying ... I was wondering if you were using the "Group" module ... that's what those URLs reminded me about ...

Comment: I guess [Menu Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) is the way to go. Unfortunately it does not work properly with D8 by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally [Menu Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) is the way to go. Once installed, created my menu entries and set them up using tokens this way:

[image]

Please notice the relative link token together with the one-level-up part before last part of path:  `/[current-page:url:relative]/../presentation`. This preserves the relative static path before the last dynamic part as in this case I wanted to make the dynamic menu relative to each `<department>/<group>` path. Also remember to check `Use tokens` and select `Method for Node: Context for Node`.

Hope it helps.